# write to file with lineseperator

Tags: java, file, line-breaks

I want to write to file and make the text use a new line after 50 letters. my code makes it to have a new line after 50 letters in the console but not in the file? What is the problem?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class Journal {

public static void journalWriter(){
    try{
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter company");
        String company = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter contact, if there is more than 1 contact     use (.) between the names");
        String contact = Scan.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Write meeting contents");
        String journalContents = Scan.nextLine();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(journalContents);

            int i = 0;
            while ((i = journalContents.indexOf(" ", i + 50)) != -1) {
                sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());


        File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Arman\\Desktop\\JavaProjekt\\Meetingjournals\\");
        dir.mkdir();    

        String dateOfMeeting = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY.MM.dd").format(new Date());


        File meetingJournal = new   File("C:\\Users\\Arman\\Desktop\\JavaProjekt\\Meetingjournals\\" + company + ".txt");




        FileWriter writeToFile = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Arman\\Desktop\\JavaProjekt\\Meetingjournals\\" + company + ".txt",true);

        if (!meetingJournal.exists()){
            meetingJournal.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(writeToFile);


        buffWriter.write(dateOfMeeting + ("\t") + ("\t") +("\t") + "Company: " + company + ("\t") + "Contact: " + contact );
        buffWriter.newLine();
        buffWriter.newLine();
        buffWriter.write(journalContents);
        buffWriter.newLine();
        buffWriter.newLine();

        buffWriter.close();

        System.out.println("Journal saved");
        System.out.println("Press enter for journalmenu");
        Scan.nextLine();



        JournalMain.main(null);
        Scan.close();

    }catch (IOException except){
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the journal contents unformatted into the file. Try to write the journal contents after formating.

replace this line:

```
buffWriter.write(journalContents);
```

by:

```
buffWriter.write(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but that didnt do it :-(